# SVD decomposition of block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd, block-matrices

Given block matrix $B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & A^{T} \\ A & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and matrix $A$ has certain SVD decompostion: $A = VDU^{T}$. My goal is finding SVD decomposition of matrix B, using matrix $A$ decompostion.

I tried this way:

$B^{T}B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & A^{T} \\ A & 0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & A \\ A^{T}& 0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} (A^{T})^2 & 0 \\ 0 & A^2 \end{pmatrix} = UD^2U^{T}$.

$A = V\Sigma U^{T}$

I tried connect matrix $D$ and $\Sigma$, but matrix D is not equal to $\Sigma^2$ so I stacked.

Can anyone forward my decision in the right way?

Comment: You have written the matrices $B$ and $B^T$ incorrectly. You should find that
$$
B^TB = B^2 = \pmatrix{0&A^T\\A&0}^2 = \pmatrix{A^TA & 0\\0 & AA^T}
$$

Comment: find [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4607574/81360) to be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

- Note that $B$ is symmetric, which means that its singular value decomposition is highly related to its [spectral decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem)
- Note, as I state in my comment, that
  $$
  B^TB = B^2 = \pmatrix{0&A^T\\A&0}^2 = \pmatrix{A^TA & 0\\0 & AA^T}
  $$
- Alternatively, note that
  $$
  B = \pmatrix{U & 0\\0& V} \pmatrix{0 & \Sigma^T\\\Sigma & 0} \pmatrix{U & 0\\0& V}^T
  $$